# Laravel - Wrong password generate 'Error' in logs

Tags: laravel

When a user puts in a bad password, I see it as the level of ERROR in the logs which does not seem like it deserves to be that critical.  I alarm off errors so I can understand health of the system.  Is there anyway to turn this down to a warning or info...

```
`production.ERROR: array (
  'error' => 'The given data was invalid.',
  'errorLine' => 71,
  'errorFile' =>
```

`/var/www/html/dashboard/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php',
  'error_catch_scope' => 'report',
  'error_catch_file' => '/var/www/html/dashboard/app/Exceptions/Handler.php',
)`

I am using laravel 5.7

Comment: can you post your `App/Exceptions/Handler.php`

Comment: Great catch, I had a custom logging function in place in that file.  Thank you!!